# Encapsulation of web components and event binding to shadow DOM elements

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

I started to learn web components in details before to jump in using Polymer.

I was working on a simple example to create a spin button using two `<button>` and one `<input type="text">` elements.

The template is:

```
<template id="tplSpinButton">
  <style type="text/css">
    .spin-button > * {
      display: inline;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="spin-button">
    <content select=".up-spin-button"></content>
    <content select=".display-spin-button"></content>
    <content select=".down-spin-button"></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the host element is as:

```
<article>
  <spin-button>
    <button class="up-spin-button">&#43;</button>
    <input class="display-spin-button" type="text" value="0" size="2"/>
    <button class="down-spin-button">&#45;</button>
  </spin-button>
</article>
```

And The JS code

```
var template = document.querySelector('#tplSpinButton');
var host = document.querySelector('article spin-button');
var articleShadowRoot = host.createShadowRoot();
articleShadowRoot.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content,true));

var counterBox = document.querySelector('.display-spin-button');
var upHandler = document.querySelector('.up-spin-button');
var downHandler = document.querySelector('.down-spin-button');
upHandler.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var count = parseInt(counterBox.value);
    counterBox.value = count + 1;
}, false);

downHandler.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var count = parseInt(counterBox.value);
    counterBox.value = count - 1;
}, false);

document.registerElement('spin-button', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

During experiments I came to know that JS/ code does not work as `<style>` do in shadow DOM being part of `<template>`
In the above example I am adding insertion points (`<content>`) and then attaching event listener to distributed elements.

- **Is there any way to encapsulate the event listener implementation?**
- **Is there any way to move the controls s and  elements to shadow dom and then attaching event listener by any way?**

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to encapsulate the event listener implementation?

You could make it part of your element's prototype and construct it inside of a [lifecycle callback](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#lifecycle).

> Is there any way to move the controls s and elements to shadow dom and then attaching event listener by any way?

Use [getDistributedNodes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-getDistributedNodes) to select the elements being projected into your content tags.

Here's [a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ropex/5/edit) which illustrates both concepts. Hope that helps!